# C# Insert BSON Document Into MongoDB

Tags: c#, json, mongodb

I've written an program that scrapes certain sites for ads, jobs, etc, and inserts a list of objects into a SQL Server database. Now I am trying to insert data into MongoDB by creating a string of JSON and parsing it to a BSON Document. But when I check to see what databases were created in MongoDB, it appears that the database is empty- no memory used, no collections exist.[image: MongoDB.exe]

```
 //A manager class calls the scraper class to retrieve lists of objects 
 //for each category and city. Then I pass a string of the data converted to 
 //JSON to the MongoDB Insert function.

 //in the Manager class
 public string JobsJson()
 {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
 }

 //in main
 JobManager manager = new JobManager();

  manager.FillJobs();

  MongoDB.InsertJobs(manager.JobsJson());

 //and the database class parses the JSON into a BSON Document.
 class MongoDB
 {
    public static void InsertJobs(string json)
    {
        var Client = new MongoClient();

        var MongoDB = Client.GetDatabase("JobSearch");

        var Collec = MongoDB.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("Gigs");

        BsonDocument document = BsonDocument.Parse(json);

        Collec.InsertOneAsync(document);         

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

I've checked the JSON by printing it to the screen to see that it is legitimate. Why is data not being stored in my MongoDB?

Comment: Try `Collec.InsertOneAsync(document).Wait();`

Comment: The top line of the prompt says that Hotfix is not installed, will zero-out data files.